# How do we create such a regular expression to extract data?

Tags: regex, string

```
<br>Aggie<br><br>John<br><p>Hello world</p><br>Mary<br><br><b>Peter</b><br>
```

I'd like to create a regexp that safely matches these:

```
<br>Aggie<br>
<br>John<br>
<br>Mary<br>
<br><b>Peter</b><br>
```

This is possible that there are other tags (e.g. `<i>`,`<strike>`...etc ) between each pair of `<br>` and they have to be collected just like the `<br><b>Peter</b><br>`

How should the regexp look like?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001311.html *sigh*

Comment: I understand it's sometimes better to do this using an HTML parser. But this is actually just a made-up example that I want to see what syntax it would be if it really has to be done in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<br>.*?<br>
```

will match anything from one `<br>` tag to the closest following one.

The main problem with parsing HTML using regexes is that regexes can't handle arbitrarily nested structures. This is not a problem in your example.

Answer (score 6):

If you learn one thing on SO, let it be -  "Do not parse HTML with a regex". Use an HTML Parser

Comment: To anyone pointing automatically to this one, quoting from the very same blog post: "Many programs will neither need to, nor should, anticipate the entire universe of HTML when parsing." It's absolutely OK to parse a HTML-like input if you keep this in mind.

Comment: This question is missing the obligatory bobince reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @candiru: The asker explicitly asked for a regexp that is **"safe"**. Regexps are fine for one-off hacks, but they are certainly not safe.

Comment: intgr: It's linked from Jeff's post I linked in the comment to the question. It's just another pointer to dereference :-)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string at `(<br>)+`. You'll get empty strings at the beginning and the end of the result, so you need to remove them, too.

If you want to preserve the `<br>`, then this is not possible unless you know that there is one before and after each element in the result.

Comment: You can still pre- and append an `<br>` to each result, though. Not nice but if the OP *requires* the `<br>` ...